# Way to support Cert and non Cert traffic at Istio

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, istio, istio-gateway

My Istio Ingress Gateway is configured in tls mode MUTUAL, and is decrypting traffic so that I can do http based routing for different services based on a query param in the http request.

I have a scenario where I need to support both Cert based and AAD based authentication. AAD Auth is being taken care at the service side, I just need to ensure I pass through traffic with Authorization header as it is (without terminating them even if they do not have a certificate) and authenticate cert based requests as well.

Similar to this issue : https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/25067

Any pointers on required config?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you tried already? Setting tls mode to `PASSTHROUGH` may help here.

Answer (score 1):

Configuring TLSMode to SIMPLE at the gateway solved the problem. To Ensure we still validate client certificate, we have put some custom logic in code.